# How do i solve the integral $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^3*e^{-ax^2}dx $

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have a hard time doing this problem can anyone help me please ?

Comment: Use integration by parts and split up as $x^2$ and $xe^{-ax^2}$.

Comment: Substitute $x^2 = t$ and then apply integration by parts

Comment: You don't need to do anything. The integral of an odd function is ... ? If you don't know try to plot the function $x^3e^{-x^2}$ on, say, $[-4,4]$ and use what you see to try to solve it (split the integral in two and use a simple substitution on one of the integrals).

Comment: One should first show the integral is convergent (not too hard using a comparison argument) before appealing to the solutions here using symmetry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using integration by parts once gives
$$\int x^3e^{-ax^2}\mathrm{d}x=-\frac{x^2}{2a}e^{-ax^2}+\frac1a\int xe^{-ax^2}dx=-\frac{x^2}{2a}e^{-ax^2}-\frac1{2a^2}e^{-ax^2}+C$$
Hence the intgeral is equal to
$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^3e^{-ax^2}\mathrm{d}x
&=\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_{-b}^0 x^3e^{-ax^2}\mathrm{d}x+\lim_{c\to\infty}\int_0^c x^3e^{-ax^2}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\lim_{b\to\infty}\left[-\frac{x^2}{2a}e^{-ax^2}-\frac1{2a^2}e^{-ax^2}\right]_{-b}^0+\lim_{c\to\infty}\left[-\frac{x^2}{2a}e^{-ax^2}-\frac1{2a^2}e^{-ax^2}\right]_0^c\\
&=\lim_{b\to\infty}\left(-\frac1{2a^2}+\frac{b^2}{2a}e^{-ab^2}+\frac1{2a^2}e^{-ab^2}\right)+\lim_{c\to\infty}\left(-\frac{c^2}{2a}e^{-ac^2}-\frac1{2a^2}e^{-ac^2}+\frac1{2a^2}\right)\\
&=-\frac1{2a^2}+\frac1{2a^2}\\
&=0\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you, it's perfect now. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

let $f(x)=x^3e^{-ax^2}$

Since the integral is in the form

$$\int_{-b}^{b} f(x) dx$$

If we can show the function is odd then the area is 0 because it cancels out.

$$-f(x)=f(-x)$$
$$-x^3e^{-ax^2}=(-x)^3e^{-a(-x)^2}$$
$$-x^3e^{-ax^2}=-x^3e^{-ax^2}$$

Hence the answer is $0$.

Comment: Your argument works when $f(x)=x$ as well, but $f$ is not integrable.

Answer (score 0):

Noticing that the integrand is an odd function allows us to show that the integral converges (by comparison test, for example), then conclude that the integral is $0.$ However, we can get there even if we don't notice that.

First of all, note that $$\frac{d}{dx}\left[e^{-ax^2}\right]=-axe^{-ax^2}$$ by Chain Rule, regardless of $a.$

Now, if $a=0,$ then the integral doesn't converge, so I assume that $a$ is non-$0,$ and that you just didn't mention it. By my assumption, we can conclude that $$xe^{-ax^2}=\frac{d}{dx}\left[-\frac1ae^{-ax^2}\right],$$ which will allow us to use integration by parts to determine an antiderivative.

\begin{eqnarray}\int x^3e^{-ax^2}dx &=& \int x^2\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\left[-\frac1ae^{-ax^2}\right]dx\\ &=& x^2\cdot-\frac1ae^{-ax^2}-\int\frac{d}{dx}\left[x^2\right]\cdot-\frac1ae^{-ax^2}dx\\ &=& -\frac1ax^2e^{-ax^2}+\frac2a\int xe^{-ax^2}dx\\ &=& -\frac1ax^2e^{-ax^2}+\frac2a\int \frac{d}{dx}\left[-\frac1ae^{-ax^2}\right]dx\\ &=& -\frac1ax^2e^{-ax^2}+\frac2a\cdot-\frac1ae^{-ax^2}\\ &=& -\frac1ax^2e^{-ax^2}-\frac2{a^2}e^{-ax^2}\\ &=& -\left(\frac1ax^2+\frac2{a^2}\right)e^{-ax^2}\end{eqnarray}

Thus,

\begin{eqnarray}\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^3e^{-ax^2}dx &=& \lim_{b\to-\infty,c\to\infty}\int_b^c x^3e^{-ax^2}dx\\ &=& \lim_{b\to-\infty,c\to\infty}-\left(\frac1ac^2+\frac2{a^2}\right)e^{-ac^2}+\left(\frac1ab^2+\frac2{a^2}\right)e^{-ab^2}\\ &=& -\lim_{c\to\infty}\left(\frac1ac^2+\frac2{a^2}\right)e^{-ac^2}+\lim_{b\to-\infty}\left(\frac1ab^2+\frac2{a^2}\right)e^{-ab^2}\\ &=& -\lim_{c\to\infty}\left(\frac1ac^2+\frac2{a^2}\right)e^{-ac^2}+\lim_{c\to\infty}\left(\frac1a(-c)^2+\frac2{a^2}\right)e^{-a(-c)^2}\\ &=& -\lim_{c\to\infty}\left(\frac1ac^2+\frac2{a^2}\right)e^{-ac^2}+\lim_{c\to\infty}\left(\frac1ac^2+\frac2{a^2}\right)e^{-ac^2}.\end{eqnarray} Consequently, if you can show that $\lim_{c\to\infty}\left(\frac1ac^2+\frac2{a^2}\right)e^{-ac^2}$ exists, then you'll have proved that the integral is $0.$